# What is the link between the energies of particles and the corresponding temperature, in context of quark gluon plasma?

Tags: quark-gluon-plasma

What is the link between the energies of particles and the corresponding temperature, in context of quark gluon plasma ?

Is quark gluon plasma existing at low or high *energy* of particles ? Or is it defined only for the *temperature* ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. Temperature is, roughly speaking, a measure of the (thermal) kinetic energy of the particles. Quark-gluon plasma is *very* hot; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagedorn_temperature

Comment: @PM 2Ring : I'm not an expert at all on QGP. Let's consider many particle that all have an energy E : what is temperature ? Is T=E ? Or is there no relationship between the two ? (this is my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quark-gluon plasma is a new state of matter - requiring either high baryon density, or high $T$ - there is a phase boundary to confined hadron phase. QGP arises as deconfined state above Hagedorn temperature $T_h=150\ MeV$ at zero baryon density.  At $T>2T_h$ it is behaving like an ideal relativistic gas with some $10$% correction due to interactions. QGP is now made from up, down, strange quarks and gluons.  These particles are practically relativistic meaning mass is small compared to kinetic energy. In a thermal relativistic gas a particle has on average the energy $E=3T$ with small variations for Bose/Fermi quantum effects. therefore the energy per quark, gluon in QGP is always above $0.5\ GeV$ and growing with temperature.